# Limit True/False

Tags: real-analysis

True or False?

If $f(x) < g(x)$ on some deleted neighborhood of point $c$, and if $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x)$ exist, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) < \lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x)$.

I've been given a theorem where I believe this holds for all "$\leq$" as opposed to "$<$". From this, I tend to believe its true, but how would I prove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False.

For example, $x^2<2x^2$ whenever $x\ne0$, but their limits as $x\to0$ are equal.

Comment: wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot, much appreciated.

Comment: Or let $f(x)=0$, $g(x)=|x|$, and $c=0$.